# How can I use search replace in visual studio with regular expression?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, replace

In the find input of visual studio I have this expression

```
<input type="submit" value=(.*) />
```

And in the replace one I have

```
<input type="submit" value=(\1) a />
```

But for some reason instead of adding an "a" it is literally replacing the code.

I mean, I am getting this

```
<input type="submit" value=(\1) a />
```

instead of this

```
<input type="submit" value="Change password" a />
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the replacement string, you need to use `$1`. `\1` is for backreferences within the search pattern. You'll also want to omit the parentheses in the replacement string.

```
<input type="submit" value=$1 a />
```

To make your pattern a bit more robust you might want to use something like

```
<input type="submit" value=("[^"*]") />
```

For the pattern. Otherwise you'll get problems if you have another self-closing tag on the same line, or an `input` tag with more attributes.